# Add UIView with Buttons and make it transparent and enable touch view behind that UIVIew

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am adding images dynamically on VIEW and on same View i have 3 buttons. but when i add images they are shown above those buttons i can send them back but i have multiple images on which i have applied gesture so when i click one image it comes to front so i can interact with it (move, rotate).

So what i have done i have mainView on which i m adding Images and i have Added childView on which i have added buttons and make it transparent. i can see that image behind buttons but cant interact with them.

I have use this line to make it transparent i think it not good way to make tranparent

```
ButtonsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope you all know what i want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey mate instead of add child view just add this button on your this same view and give backgroundColor clear  and then in this bellow method try this..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [touch locationInView:yourView];
else if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        UIImageView *tempImage=(UIImageView *) touch.view;
        [yourView bringSubviewToFront:tempImage];
        [yourView bringSubviewToFront:yourButtons];/// set superview as a buttons..
    }
}
```

i hope this help you..

Comment: Thanks paras , i didnt implement touchesBegan. i just showed my image in front and then my buttons in front. i have used this for(UIButton *b in self.view.subviews) {
        if([b isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:b];
        }
    } to bring every buttons on front. Thanks